# PHP: Enter page ONLY via button?

Tags: php, post

Im making a process consisting of multiple pages and i want the user to only be able to get to "Checkout1.php" by clicking a button from the shopping cart page(showCart.php). Theres also a login check that works.

checkOut1.php :

```
<article id="content">
    <h2>Check Out</h2>

    <h3><span class="checkOut">1. Get Delivery Details</span> -> 2. Confirm Order -> 3. Make Payment -> 
4. Print Order Confirmation</h3>

    <?php
    if ((isset($_POST['submitShowCart'])) || (isset($_POST['returnCheckOut2'])) || 
    (isset($_POST['submitLogin']))) {

        if ($_SESSION['login']=='valid') {
        echo "<p>Please modify delivery details as necessary and continue the Check Out process:</p>";

    ?>

        //Blah blah blah (Main Form Code)

    <form method="post" action="showCart.php">
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Return To Shopping Cart" name="returnCheckOut1">
        </p>
    </form>

    <br><p>* = Required Fields</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="intLink">[Top]</a></p>

    <?php
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>Please login to continue the Check Out process.</p>";
    }
}
    else {
    // display no access message
    echo "<p>Cannot access this file directly - must come via the Check Out process.</p>";
    } 
    ?>
</article>
```

showCart.php :

```
<article id="content">
    <h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>

<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    echo "<p>Your shopping cart is currently empty.</p>";
}
else {
?>

<!-- open form so that qtyOrdered field becomes an input element -->
<form action="updateCart.php" method="post">

<!-- display headings for cart -->
<table class="prod1">
    <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Quantity On Hand</th>
    <th>Quantity Ordered</th>
    <th>Unit Price $</th>
    <th>Extended Value $</th>
</tr>

<?php
// set up starting value of grand total
$grandTotal = 0;

// read details from the cart session variable and display
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $prodNbr=>$value) {
    // extract data into separate variable
    $prodName = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['prodName'];
    $price = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['price'];
    $qtyOnHand = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['qtyOnHand'];
    $qtyOrdered = $_SESSION['cart'][$prodNbr]['qtyOrdered'];

    // do calculation for extended value
    $extendedValue = $qtyOrdered * $price;

    // accumulate the grand total of extended value column
    $grandTotal = $grandTotal + $extendedValue;

    // display fields in a table row
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$prodName</td>";
    echo "<td class='right'>$qtyOnHand</td>";
    echo "<td class='right'><input type='text' value='$qtyOrdered' size='2' name='qtyToBuy[$prodNbr]' /></td>";
    echo "<td class='right'>$price</td>";
    echo "<td class='right'>".number_format("$extendedValue",2)."</td>";
    if ($qtyOrdered == $qtyOnHand) {
        echo "<td><strong>No further stock available</strong></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
} // end of foreach loop

    // display the grand total
    echo "<tr><td colspan='4' class='right'><strong>Grand Total : </strong></td><td class='right highlight'>" .number_format("$grandTotal",2) ."</td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update Cart'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<h3>Enter a new quantity ordered OR 0 to remove the item from your cart.</h3>";
?>

<input type="button" value="Check Out" onclick="javascript:location.replace('checkOut1.php')" />    
<input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" onclick="javascript:location.replace('catalogue.php')" />

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</article>
```

EDIT: I want checkout1 to check if the user came to that page from showCart, the code i have now doesn't check and always gives me the " Cannot access this file directly - must come via the Check Out process." message.

Comment: And what do you want ?

Comment: check `$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the user comes from showCart.php to checkout.php add this to checkout.php:

```
if(basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])=="showCart.php"){
//do your code of checkout.php
}
else{
//show error message and redirect the page.
}
```

Comment: That got it working, thanks.  I replaced the first "IF" line in checkout.

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks on the button you can set a `SESSION` variable and on the target page  you can check that whether that `SESSION` variable is set or not. If it is set then display the page else don't display.

Comment: The thing is i had this working before using pretty much this code without using SESSION variables and such. If possible id rather use this POST stuff i have. I will look into SESSION variables though.        EDIT: I followed Drarkayls soluttion and it worked, you were right about the Session variables. My bad :v